# Changes in div content are not reflecting in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

[image: I am trying to change the content of div "info" using the script as shown below]

I am trying to change the content of div "info" using the script as shown below
[image: Code]

But We can see that the content of the div is changing in the inspected screen and Not reflecting in the browser screen.

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
function GeneratePaySlips() {
    ShowLoaderOnElement(".btn-generate");
    if ($("#driverIDs").val().length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        var driverIDs = $("#driverIDs").val().split(',');
        //for (var i = 0; i < driverIDs.length; i++)
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = i + 1 + ' of ' + $("#totalDrivers").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { "driverID": driverIDs[i] },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                url: '/BulkPaySlip/GeneratePaySlip',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.isSuccess) {
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    HideLoaderOnElement(".btn-generate");
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
        }
        if (i >= driverIDs.length) {
            HideLoaderOnElement(".btn-generate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you link us to a sample, so we can attempt to debug it?

Comment: If the debugger says the text is there, but it's simply not showing up, then this might be a CSS problem, not a javascript problem. Try adding `background:red !important; font-size:16px !important;white-space:nowrap;` to make sure that you're actually looking at the right place, and that it's not simply being hidden by `overflow:hidden;`or something silly like that.

Comment: Another easy way to tell if your javascript is related to the problem is to double-click on it, and change the text by hand to `Lorem ipsum dolor sit`. If you don't see it all, then check your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

So I can’t see all the code but maybe put the code in a  < script > tag right before the html element and then see what happens.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

    function GeneratePaySlips() {
        ShowLoaderOnElement(".btn-generate");
        if ($("#driverIDs").val().length > 0) {
            var i = 0;
            var driverIDs = $("#driverIDs").val().split(',');
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                document.getElementById("info").value=i + 1 + ' of ' + $("#totalDrivers").val();
            }
            if (i >= driverIDs.length) {
                HideLoaderOnElement(".btn-generate");
            }
        }
    }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

First of all `innnerHTML` is used to change the content of the specified element you called. On your above codes, the contents will go to the div element without creating any elements tags thus not displaying the content you wanted.
The below code can work if you need to create another element on DIV tag

```
.innerHTML = '<p>' + $('#totalDrivers').value + '</p>
```

or you can try and create a new element which you can later append to the div five times according to your for loop. Run the code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement('p')
    var text = $('#totalDrivers').value /* You can use strings to show the result fast // var text = 'i am coming' // */
    element.textContent = text
    document.getElementById('text').appendChild(element)
}
```

The codes are self-explanatory, sorry for mentioning this.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please check my function?

Comment: Just change the following to one of the above examples i suggested and tit will work. Change the following:  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = i + 1 + ' of ' + $("#totalDrivers").val();   Working on mine